# Adding previous values in LinExpr

Tags: python, gurobi

I want to add previous value of a linear expression to the current one as long as the loop runs. Currently it just adds the current value twice. 
1. What should I change in my code to achieve that?
2. Is there any built in function that could add/multiply all the previous values in a linear expression?

The output it gives is

```
<gurobi.LinExpr: y_1 + y_1>
<gurobi.LinExpr: y_2 + y_2>
```

While I want it to give

```
<gurobi.LinExpr: y_2 + y_1>
```

Following is my code.

```
from gurobipy import LinExpr , GRB, Model
model= Model()
Vars = dict()
def creatingvarriables():
    for t in range(1,3,1):
        Vars["y_" + str(t)] = model.addVar(vtype=GRB.BINARY,name="y_" + str(t))
        lhs = Vars["y_" + str(t)]
        lhs = LinExpr(1,Vars["y_" + str(t)])
        model.update()
        z = lhs.add(lhs)
        print lhs
creatingvarriables()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lhs variable gets overwritten in every loop, which is why you end up adding it to itself before it is printed. Use a different variable to store the LinExpr that you want to add to in every loop.

Also, Gurobi can generate multiple variables by passing a list (or multiple) to the .addVars method, like so:

```
times = range(1, 3, 1)
Vars = model.addVars(times, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="y_")
```

This gives you the advantage of generating a [tupledict](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/refman/py_tupledict.html) object, which can be used quite elegantly in your constraints or target function.

Instead of explicitly writing a LinExpr you can use gurobi's [quicksum](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/refman/py_quicksum.html) functionality:

```
lhs = quicksum(Vars[t] for t in times)
```

or even shorter:

```
lhs = Vars.sum()
```

Documentation on the .sum() method for a tupledict can be found [here](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/7.5/refman/py_tupledict_sum.html).